# How to display Channel entry page?

Tags: channel-entries

When looping through Channel entries, is there a way to provide users with a link they can click on that will take them to that specific Channel entry? I seem to recall seeing some "url" variable available within `{exp:channel:entries}` tag pair, but can't find it again.

Also, once I'm on that specific Channel entry page, how do I know which entry it is so I can display the rest of the Channel's data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an index or listing page, like  products, your code maybe like

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="10" orderby="date" sort="desc"}

    <div class="pic-wall"><a href=/product/profile/{url_title}"><img src="/images/product/{product_image_file}" alt="{title}"></a></div>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

then on your product profile page, you'd want something like

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="product" limit="1"}

<h2>{title}</h2>
{product_description}
<hr />
{other_fields}


{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Additionally, you can use the `url_title="{segment_3}"` to make sure the record exists, or the if no_results option so that random urls, if generated will result in a 404 call.

The key component is to either use the {url_title}, {entry_id}, {comment_entry_id_auto_path}, or {permalink}. There are a few more options, but they are basically variations of the above for example:

`{url_title}` will allow you to custom create the path to the entry like

```
<a href="{domain}/products/detail/{url_title}" title="{title}">{title}</a>
```

or you could use {url_title_path}. {url_title_path} assumes you've completed the details in channel profiles, when you were setting things up, so if you said the default path for products was `products/details` it will use that, but if you said it was `products/index` then it would have the wrong path.

I tend to use the {url_title} because I like the flexibility, one of the other developers I work with prefers using the {url_title_path} option. But both will create a link, so that you can design a template with detail specific fields.

Take a look at http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#parameters to see all the various parameter options available to you.

Comment: OK - I understand `url_title` now. What I don't understand is the "profile page." How does it know which entry it's trying to display? Does it make certain assumptions based on the URL?

Comment: No the {url_title}, is unique per section or you can use the {entry_id}, but the {url_title} is more SEO and user friendly. It would change `<a href="{domain}/products/detail/{url_title}" title="{title}">{title}</a>` to `<a href="http://mydomain.org/products/profile/cat_knitting_tee_shirt" title="Cat Knitting Tee">Cat Knitting Tee</a>`

Answer (score 2):

My preferred method is to use [**{comment_url_title_auto_path}**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#comment-url-title-auto-path). I find that this is the most future proof method since if your urls change in the future for some reason then you only need to make a change in the url settings for that specific channel and not throughout all of your templates. In your specific channel go to admin > channel Preferences > channel name and be sure to fill out the **comment page url** with the segment of where that channel should appear. For example if it's for your blog page which has a url like this domain.com/blog/url_title then in that setting you would put **blog**.

Comment: We always create a variable, called {domain} in the path.php or index.php file using global variables, that way, this `<a href="{domain}/products/detail/{url_title}" title="{title}">{title}</a>` will work. That maybe because we frequently use the old method of creating subsites, instead of MSM. Though most of the developers I know use relative paths.

Comment: Why `{domain}`? Why not just use `{site_url}`?

Comment: It's part of a grouping of global variables that we test against. I can't recall why we first needed it, but `{site_url}` was returning current url, and we had need for if these 3 criteria were match, the link would point to a sub site domain, like mydomain2.org, even if current domain was domain.org.