# Channel entry not displaying

Tags: templates, channel-entries

RE: [How to display Channel entry page?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/how-to-display-channel-entry-page)

The accepted solution doesn't seem to work for me. My "products/index" template has something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="10" orderby="date" sort="desc"}
   <a href=/products/detail/{url_title}">{name}</a>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then in "products/detail" template, I have something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="1"}
   <h2>{name}</h2>
   <p>{description}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The "products/detail" page always shows the same record (and when you look at the tag pair, it make sense I think). How is this template supposed to know which record specifically to access? What is it about `{url_title}` that hints to which entry to retrieve? Is there something I need to put in the tag pair to tell it to use the `{url_title}` segment?

Comment: When ExpressionEngine is set-up in dynamic mode, segment_3 triggers the look-up of the entry_id, title, and other parameters. If the title or entry_id is not provided in segment_3, then turn dynamic-off, and trigger the look-up based on either `{url_title}` or `{entry_id}` in the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag, such as `{exp:channel:entries channel="products" url_title="{segment_4}" dynamic="off" limit="1"}` where segment would be whichever segment you are using, 2, 4, etc. Also, test with the `{title}` field it will provide a better idea of what's being pulled, if anything.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that the **last {segment}** will trigger the lookup (not just {segment_3}).  If it's an integer, then EE looks up by entry_id.  If it's a string, it looks up by entry_url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct, and should work. EE will always look at the third segment for either an `entry_id` or `url_title`, unless you specifically add `dynamic="no"` to your Channel Entries tag. So although the suggestions that you specify `entry_id="{segment_3}"` or `url_title="{segment_3}"` will work, they should not be necessary.

Note that in your first code sample, you should use `{permalink="products/detail"}` or `{title_permalink="products/detail"}` - more future-proof.

Comment: `dynamic="no"` was not included, so I'm not sure why it wasn't looking at `segment_3`. Yes, I'm actually using `{permalink="products/detail"}`.

Answer (score 2):

You could add url_title="{segment_3}" to the channel entries tag in the products/detail template.

Comment: And dynamic="no" ad I would normally use and as above points out.

Answer (score 1):

On your details template, you can add two parameters to the entries loop that should solve this - add dynamic="no" and url_title="{segment_3}".

Comment: There are other options than `url_title`. Say I use `entry_id`, do I then just add entry_id="{segment_3}"? I'm actually using `permalink` for testing.

Comment: Using `permalink` in the `products/index` template. `products/details` seems to work when I use `entry_id="{segment_3}"`. `permalink="{segment_3}"` did not work. Are these correct?